# Styles from E-Mails influence form css style

Tags: css, outlook, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin, microsoft-dynamics

**Track - Function**

We are using the dynamics crm 2015 outlook add in to synchronize e-mails from Outlook to Dynamics CRM.
With this tool, e-mails from Outlook can be attached to Dynamics CRM Entities.

Unfortunately some of the e-mails that users track contain inline css - styles.
Somehow these styles aren't removed by dynamics CRM and now these embedded styles influence the standard - css of Dynamics CRM so it is no longer properly displayed.

Is there a way to disable all CSS - styles from those tracked e-mails or some other propability?

There already is a hint that script code is blocked, but it seems that css is not blocked... Can it be blocked to?
[image: script blocked but css styles not blocked]

Dynamics CRM 2015 is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to strip the CSS/HTML tags from the email body & store the plain text on email receipt.

Though this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukcrm/2008/07/10/converting-html-e-mail-to-plain-text/) is old but outlines the steps you have to follow.

You need a plugin in Email entity to run on `DeliverPromote` message (any e-mail promoted from Outlook triggers the "DeliverPromote" event), strip out the not-needed things from the Email body & store in CRM.

Comment: thx for the hint. I think I will pursui this solution. But first I have to deal with the problem, that there already are E-Mails in the system, that are influencing the css style. I decided to reopen those E-Mails ansd strip the style

Answer (score 2):

To edit the mails that contained the css style the mails were opened by using

```
osp = new OrganizationServiceProxy(..)

Entity mailEnt = xrmServiceContext.EmailSet.Where(email => email.Subject.StartsWith("..."));

SetStateRequest ssr = new SetStateRequest();
ssr.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(mailEnt.LogicalName, mailEnt.Id);
ssr.State = new OptionSetValue(0);
ssr.Status = new OptionSetValue(1);
```

then the body was edited using a replacement method

```
emailEnt["description"] = trimmedBody;
osp.Update(emailEnt);
```

finally the email states were set back to received

```
SetStateRequest ssr = new SetStateRequest();
ssr.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(mailEnt.LogicalName, mailEnt.Id);
ssr.State = new OptionSetValue(1);
ssr.Status = new OptionSetValue(4); // 2 completed // 4 Received
```